# Loading BaseFont from embedded resource in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using iTextSharp to generate dynamic PDF documents. I have a requirement to use a very specific font for which I have the licensed .ttf file.

I can use the code the below to load and use the font, however I would much prefer to have the font file as located as an embedded resource in my class library rather than being reliant on a specific location on disk.

```
string fontpath = Server.MapPath(".");
BaseFont customfont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontpath + "myspecial.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252,    BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(customfont, 12);
string s = "My expensive custom font.";
doc.Add(new Paragraph(s, font));
```

Can anybody help me as to how I might achieve this?

Comment: Checkout this link to ITextSharp's site http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/81/iTextSharp-Working-with-Fonts

Comment: @DJKRAZE - Where in the site you referenced does it talk about loading a font from an embedded resource?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After reviewing the ITextSharp source it looks like you may be able to use the following overload of `BaseFont.CreateFont` to use your embedded resource as a font (line 543 from [BaseFont.cs](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/BaseFont.cs?revision=296&view=markup)):

```
public static BaseFont CreateFont(String name, String encoding, bool embedded, bool cached, byte[] ttfAfm, byte[] pfb)
```

`ttfAfm` should represent the TTF file as a `byte[]`.

Comment: +1 - If you don't already know the [API is here](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/), and the [BaseFont docs are here](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseFont.html). In Java, but either the same in .NET or close enough to figure out. Or if you *like* looking at the source code, disregard ;)

Comment: Thanks for the steer, I managed to get the code working which I've posted below.

Answer (score 7):

This is example code on how to do it:

```
Stream fontStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("font.resource.path.fontfilename.ttf");
var fontBytes = ReadByteArray(fontStream);
var customFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("fontfilename.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, BaseFont.CACHED, fontBytes, null);
```

I also found that not setting the font name (first param of CreatFont()) threw an obscure exception, but specifying the exact name of the font file worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can get fontBytes directly from resources. In example below I have resource file named "FontFiles.resx"

```
var customFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("fontfilename.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, BaseFont.CACHED, FontFiles.fontfilename, null);
```